# Jquery click() on "a"-element

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, onclick

I was wondering why Jquery.onClick() won't let you follow links and open new windows.
I tried to "simulate" a click on a link like here but it won't work. Why?

```
$('#link').click();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wCRLE/5/

Comment: That's because it only triggers the event handlers set with javascript, and not native events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would trigger any `click` event listeners you've added to the element, not trigger the native functionality.

You could do something similar by doing this:

```
window.open($('#link').attr('href'));
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wCRLE/8/

On a side note, it's a good idea to avoid defining your click events inline with your HTML tag. I've modified your jsFiddle to show how you could do it using jQuery.